Flutter layout constraints. How can a sized box be unconstrained when it has dimensions?
I have this code:
Column(
  children: [
    Row(
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          height: 20,
          width: 20,
        )
      ],
    )
  ],
)

I get a warning in the DevTools that the SizedBox is unconstrained. How is that even possible? It has specified dimensions. Obviously Flutter is not behaving in a way that feels logical in this situation. However, I would like to understand why this is, and how my SizedBox should be constrained properly? What is best practise here? Also let's say I have multiple SizeBox in the same Row/Column, what would be the best praxis then?

Could you provide the code of the entire view that is throwing this error? I pasted your code into an empty view and assigned a Text widget as a child to the SizedBox and it worked fine.

Could it be that my main is wrapped in a SingleChildScrollView? Didn't even think about that widget being the parent of the Column. Is that the issue? How would I fix it in that case?

I would not be able to assist you further without the minimum code to reproduce the error. With that I would be happy to help.
